# wait until XHR request finished

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using wait until `lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0")` to make sure page loads and finished ajax call.

But when I click on one of the buttons I see XHR call going on in network log but `window.jQuery` shows `undefined`, so I can't use above command.

How can I wait until XHR call finishes or I get response.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0")
```

Comment: How does your js code looks like?
usually when calling `$.ajax`, you have a `success` and an `error` callback to check if your call failed or works

Comment: @toffler added code

Comment: Could it be the xhr is sent from a js code that's not jQuery - a vanilla javascript doing it? `jQuery.active` is an internal counter which the framework increments itself, so if the call was outside of jQuery that would explain it. If that's so, you can wait for/confirm the xhr completion by the page's state change - it must "do" something for the page, like changing or adding data.

Comment: @user2661518 I've found this for selenium ajax, I hope it helps with your problem: [Handle Ajax in Selenium](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/handle-ajax-call-using-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

you can wait until xhr finished by setting ajax  async: false.

To use ajax you must have jQuery library only then it will work

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/submit/checkuser/",
    type : "get",
    async: false,
    success : function(userStatus) {
       if (userStatus == 'Disabled') { // check if user if disabled                    
       } else if (userStatus == 'Deleted') { // check if user if deleted
       } else {
       };
    },
    error: function() {
       connectionError();
    }
 });
```

This ajax is asyc false so that it complete its execution and moved to the next function

For python selenium please refer the url below

[webdriver wait for ajax request in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053671/webdriver-wait-for-ajax-request-in-python)

Comment: How can I do this in python selenium, added my current code

Comment: @user2661518  for python selenium i have attached a url please refer it .

Comment: I tried `return document.readyState` but it shows `complete` even if page is loading, maybe it's because it's async call?