# How to use selenium to select an option in the dropdown menu which has AJAX onchange attribute

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I've been going through a few other pages on stackoverflow but failed to find a solution that solves my problem now. I am trying to use selenium (python) to automate a work process. It involves logging in the web portal, selecting a few search criteria, and then download the files. I am stuck with the selection part. I can click on other dropdown menu on the same page by not this one:

```
    <select id="fMain:j_id162:rangeLineIdlocation1" name="fMain:j_id162:rangeLineIdlocation1" size="1" onchange="if(MMIS.Event.delay(this, arguments)) return true;A4J.AJAX.Submit('fMain',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'fMain:j_id162:j_id165','containerId':'fMain:j_id161','parameters':{'fMain:j_id162:j_id165':'fMain:j_id162:j_id165'} } )"> 
        <option value=" "> </option>
        <option value="10000109">AEL</option>
        <option value="10000123">AEL+TCL</option>
    </select>
```

I have tried using the method suggested in
[webdriver wait for ajax request in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053671/webdriver-wait-for-ajax-request-in-python)

```
    try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fMain:j_id165:rangeLineIdlocation1"]')))
finally:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fMain:j_id165:rangeLineIdlocation1"]/option[1]').click()
```

But it didn't work. I'm currently stuck in here now. Any clue? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using Select class methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Wait for element and then create a select type element.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fMain:j_id165:rangeLineIdlocation1"]')))
dropdown = Select(element )
```

Then use any of the below

**By Index:**

```
dropdown.select_by_index(0) #It will select options by index. in this case 0 =AEL, 1 = AEL+TCL
```

**By Visible Text:**

```
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("AEL") #It will match Inner Html to select option. in this case it will match AEL
```

**By Value**

```
dropdown.select_by_value("10000109") # It will use attribute value to select option
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<option>` with text as **AEL** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `select_by_visible_text()`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[id*='rangeLineIdlocation1'][name*='rangeLineIdlocation1']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text('AEL')
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `select_by_value()`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[contains(@id, "rangeLineIdlocation1")][contains(@name,'rangeLineIdlocation1')]"))))
  select.select_by_value('10000109')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```